# Glossaries with numberlist also counts TOC, LOF, LOT

Tags: sectioning, table-of-contents, glossaries

I am using glossaries to maintain a list of acronyms.

I want it to display the page number where it appears.

I usually use `\acs{}` or `\acl{}` in sectioning title or in caption.

However I noticed that glossaries also displays the page of TOC, LOF or LOT if I use `\acs{}` or `\acl{}` inside `\section{}` or `\caption` (as this entries will appear in TOC, LOF, or LOT).

How can I disable this behavior of glossaries and only consider what is really the text, there is, not consider what is written in TOC, LOF, or LOT?

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[section,xindy,nomain,acronym,toc,shortcuts]{glossaries}

\newcommand{\acro}[2]{\newacronym{#1}{#1}{#2}}

\acro{MIMO}{Multiple Input Multiple Output}
\acro{SISO}{Single Input Single Output}

\makeglossaries

\newcommand{\acroname}{Acronym}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\printglossary[type=\acronymtype,style=tree,title=\acroname,toctitle=\acroname]

\newpage

\section{\acs*{MIMO} and \acs*{SISO}}

bla

\end{document}
```

If I take the previous code and do:

```
pdflatex test
makeglossaries test
pdflatex test
makeglossaries test
pdflatex test
```

The output is in the attached file. Note that the second `makeglossaries` runs automatically because I also have `biber`. If the second `makeglossaries` does not run, everything is ok.

[image: Output file]

Is there a way to prevent this and allow the run of second `\makeglossaries`?

Comment: I would like to help, but don't have `xindy`. Can you make an example without it? Maybe this already helps you: try `\texorpdfstring`.

Comment: To use the previous example without `xindy` just remove it from the glossaries options:
`\usepackage[section,nomain,acronym,toc,shortcuts]{glossaries}` I also used `\texorpdfstring` but it only takes care of bookmarks and not the text itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`glossaries`](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/glossaries-user.pdf) package provides `\glsentry<field>` commands that
do nothing but expand to the `<field>` value. Thus, try:

```
\section{\glsentryshort{MIMO} and \glsentryshort{SISO}}
\glsadd{MIMO}
\glsadd{SISO}
```

Alternatively, you could try:

```
\section[\glsentryshort{MIMO} and \glsentryshort{SISO}]{\acs*{MIMO} and \acs*{SISO}}
```

Comment: This does the trick. At least part of it. However I am also trying to keep some compatibility with `acronym` package in a way that with the same list of acronyms I can use either packages. Thus if I have a flag=true I will use `glossaries` else I will use `acronym`. Therefore I need to build two new commands (for short and long versions) for each of the packages that display the acronym in the table but does not hyperlink it. These commands will only be used inside `\caption{}` or `\section{}`. Example: `\newcommand{\acsnh}[1]{\glsentryshort{#1}\glsadd{#1}}`. But I don't now about `acronym`.

Comment: @user16720: If you use `\acsnh` in the argument of `\section` you’ll have the same problem as before.

Comment: @user16720: I’ve added an alternative solution.

Comment: I tried to use `\caption{This section is about \glslink*{MIMO}{\glsentryshort{MIMO}}` with no luck. It seems that there is no way instead of using `\glsadd{}` outside `\caption{}` or `\caption[]{}`.

Comment: @cacamailg: `\caption` is to be treated analogously to `\section`: Thus, either `\caption{\glsentryshort{MIMO}}\glsadd{MIMO}` or `\caption[\glsentryshort{MIMO}]{\acs*{MIMO}}`.

Comment: How could this be done for ordinary glossary entries rather than acronym entries?